# Would Apple allow V8-powered Javascript apps on iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios

There's been a lot of talk about Google being forced to go with UIWebView for Chrome for iOS, and Facebook ditching HTML5 entirely for their iOS apps because UIWebView was too slow. I'll soon be needing to port an HTML5 application that requires lots of intensive Javascript computations (too much code to rewrite natively given my time constraints) but none of the display functionality that a browser provides (i.e. it works fine headlessly on Node.js). I've never heard of anyone trying to embed Google's V8 into an iOS app, but given that [MobiRuby](http://mobiruby.org/) does practically the same thing (linking in the mruby interpreter), would it be permissible to do something similar, linking in Google's V8 interpreter within the same process? As long as code isn't downloaded, and processes aren't forked, it doesn't seem to be against the rules, but has anyone ever tried this?

EDIT: I'm aware of PhoneGap/Cordova and similar technologies, but they all work with a full UIWebView, and due to Apple's paranoia, UIWebView cannot JIT-compile Javascript code (which, as I said, is essential for my application).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to what is mentioned in this this [thread](http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=1312) on the v8-dev mailing list, it may now be possible. You may be interested in the state of the work on this issue.

Comment: Hmm, it seems that this process would be a lot more involved than I thought... thanks for the link though!